# R cast string to raw?

Tags: r, binary

How do I convert from `"character"` to `"raw"`?

```
class ( plot_binary  )
# [1] "raw"
plot_binary[3]
# [1] 4e
class ( plot_binary[3] ) 
# [1] "raw"
```

I want to do a conversion from a character `"4e"` to a raw `4e`.

How do I do this?

`as.raw` obviously not work because

```
as.raw("4e")
# [1] 04
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
as.raw ( as.hexmode ( "4e" ) )
#[1] 4e
```

Answer (score 5):

Try looking at: `rawToChar` and `charToRaw`

Answer (score 1):

R accepts hexadecimal numeric input prefixed with `0x`.

```
> as.raw(0x4e)
[1] 4e
```